# asp.net MVC routing eror 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i dont understand the rooting in ASP.net ; im missing something with this ?
this is my root :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChampionID",
                url: "Champion/ChampionById/id",
                defaults: new { controller = "Champion", action = "ChampionById", id = "5" }
            );
```

this is my Controler :

```
public class ChampionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ChampionById(string x)
    {
        ChampionId ch = new ChampionId();
        ch.Id = x;
        return View(ch);
    }
```

if you can help me with this i will be thankful

Comment: what URL you are entering in browser?

Comment: You return a View named `ChampionById`, do you have a view with that name?

Comment: It need to be `url: "Champion/ChampionById/{id}",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget routes.MapRoute.  Just wire up all routes and then put the route as an attribute like this:

```
public class ChampionController : Controller
{
    [Route("Champion/ChampionById/{id}")]
    public ActionResult ChampionById(string id)
    {
       ChampionId ch = new ChampionId();
       ch.Id = id;
       return View(ch);
    }
}
```

Also x should be id.  Then just remove routes.MapRoute.  Then make sure you have a corresponding cshtml file called ChampionById.

Comment: thanks with this attribute , you force him to take the right route (this is tested and it worked )

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to below to fit you ActionResult like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChampionID",
                url: "Champion/ChampionById/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Champion", action = "ChampionById", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Note what I have updated with 'id'

Here all requests with 'Champion/ChampionById/' pattern will be mapped to this route and any thing after 'Champion/ChampionById/' will be the 'id parameter'. Since it is marked as optional on the route this can be null too. So better check for it.

```
public class ChampionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ChampionById(string id)
    {
        ChampionId ch = new ChampionId();

        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        { 
            ch.Id = id;
            return View(ch);
        }
        //<TODO> : handle when your id parameter is null
        return View(ch);
    }
```

Comment: thank you this is working for me i will edite the post = )

Comment: @MaroineAbdellah Glad it helped you. Please accept as answer if it helped you. Just had a look on your previous question you have not accepted an answer for any. This will make people not to answer you for future questions :) Please keep up the SO spirit and accept an answer. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

edit your route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChampionID",
                url: "Champion/ChampionById/{x}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Champion", action = "ChampionById", x = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```